# Problema con conexiones en Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

tengo un problema con un proyecto que estoy desarrollando en Swift, es para clase y me estoy encontrado con una traba que con consigo solucionar por más que lo intento. Os explico:

A partir del proyecto de FoodTracker que se desarrolla en la [guía de Apple para Desarrolladores](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/) estoy intentado crear un Tab Bar Controller que en una vista muestre el nombre de la comida, en otra la foto y en otra la puntuación. El problema es que para que me muestre estos datos, en la clase `MealTableViewController.swift` hay un método que se llama `prepare` que es el que hace que se me muestren los datos en la vista nueva, pero tal y como lo hacen en la guía que he dicho antes, no consigo que eso funcione. Os he dejado el código tal cual lo tengo en un [repositorio de github](https://github.com/anonimous231/TabBarController.git).

El método que os comento está ahora así:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)

    switch(segue.identifier ?? "") {

    case "AddItem":
        os_log("Adding a new meal.", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)

    case "ShowDetail":
        guard let mealDetailViewController = segue.destination as? NameMealViewController else {
            fatalError("Unexpected destination: \(segue.destination)")
        }

        guard let selectedMealCell = sender as? MealTableViewCell else {
            fatalError("Unexpected sender: \(String(describing: sender))")
        }

        guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: selectedMealCell) else {
            fatalError("The selected cell is not being displayed by the table")
        }

        let selectedMeal = meals[indexPath.row]
        mealDetailViewController.meal = selectedMeal

    default:
        fatalError("Unexpected Segue Identifier; \(String(describing: segue.identifier))")
    }
}
```

El caso es que sé que está mal porque el `segue.destination` no es `NameMealViewController` ya que el segue va a un `UITabBarController` pero de esta forma no puedo pasarle la comida que se ha seleccionado.

necesito ayuda para solucionar esto ya que llevo ya un par de semanas pensando en cómo hacerlo y no lo consigo.

Muchas gracias por todo. Os recomiendo descargar el repositorio para ver mejor cual es el problema que os comento.

Un saludo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola la solución a tu problema es de hecho muy sencilla. Lo único que tienes que hacer es modificar el método de `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` de la siguiente manera.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)

    switch(segue.identifier ?? "") {

    case "AddItem":
        os_log("Adding a new meal.", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)

    case "ShowDetail":
        guard let tabBarController = segue.destination as? UITabBarController else {
            fatalError("Unexpected destination: \(segue.destination)")
        }
        guard let mealDetailViewController = tabBarController.viewControllers?.first as? NameMealViewController else {
            fatalError("Couldn't instantiate NameMealViewController from tabbar")
        }

        guard let selectedMealCell = sender as? MealTableViewCell else {
            fatalError("Unexpected sender: \(String(describing: sender))")
        }

        guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: selectedMealCell) else {
            fatalError("The selected cell is not being displayed by the table")
        }

        let selectedMeal = meals[indexPath.row]
        mealDetailViewController.meal = selectedMeal

    default:
        fatalError("Unexpected Segue Identifier; \(String(describing: segue.identifier))")
    }
}
```

La modificación que se hizo es castear el `segue.destination` a un ViewController de clase `UITabBarController` y instancear el tu ViewController `NameMealViewController` a partir del primer ViewController del `UITabBarController`.

Sabía que era el primer ViewController de la TabBar, porqué abrí tu storyboard y era el primero de izquierda a derecha.

Saludos

Comment: Hola Pablo, es justamente lo que me comentas. Hasta ahora solo había seguido el tutorial completo que dije en la pregunta y como no hablan del Tab Bar Controller, me puse a investigar y llegué al punto que no sabía como continuar. Te agredezco muchísimo la solución. Eres un grande ;)

Comment: Ahora tengo otra duda, si necesito meter un Navigation Controller entre el Tab Bar Controller y el View Controller, Cómo quedaría el prepare?

Comment: @Alfred la solución sería sencilla, tendrías que obtener primero la instancia del tabbar como hicimos anteriormente, después deberías obtener una instancia del navigation, de igual manera que obtuvimos la del NameMealViewController anteriormente y finalmente obtienes el rootviewcontroller del navigation controller que es nuestro NameMealViewController. Te recomiendo que hagas una nueva pregunta, para que haya mayor claridad para los siguientes usuarios con duda.

Comment: Muchas gracias por todo!! Voy a crear otra pregunta pues esto ya he conseguido que funcione y solo me queda meter la funcionalidad de que cuando cambie algo, pueda guardarlo.